# GCC 4.8.2 vectorization avoid simple loop

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization

Here is excerpt from my C code. I hope I copied all relevant parts.

```
#define SIN_LEN 22050
#define CALC_N 4100
#define CHUNK_LEN 22050

float __attribute__((aligned(16))) sin_array[SIN_LEN];
float __attribute__((aligned(16))) cos_array[SIN_LEN];
short __attribute__((aligned(16))) data[CHUNK_LEN];
size_t __attribute__((aligned(16))) a1[CHUNK_LEN];
float sinus_sum  __attribute__((aligned(16)));
float cosinus_sum __attribute__((aligned(16)));
float __attribute__((aligned(16))) temp1[CHUNK_LEN];
float __attribute__((aligned(16))) temp2[CHUNK_LEN];

void sin_summ(long n, float* restrict sin_s, float* restrict cos_s ) {
    sinus_sum = 0;
    cosinus_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_LEN; i++ ) 
        a1[i] = (n*i) % SIN_LEN;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_LEN; i++) {
        temp1[i] = sin_array[a1[i]];
        temp2[i] = cos_array[a1[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_LEN; i++) {
        sinus_sum += data[i] * temp1[i];
        cosinus_sum += data[i] * temp2[i];
    }
    *sin_s = sinus_sum;
    *cos_s = cosinus_sum;
    return;
}
```

Function `sin_summ` is called in loop too. The GCC parameters are `-O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi=hard -ffast-math -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1 -funsafe-math-optimizations -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing` The architecture is armv7-neon (BeagleBone Black).

*The problem is* loops #1  and #3 are vectorized, but #2 is not. I guess it is because of `[a[i]]` part. **Somebody please suggest how to make it vectorizable.** Right now single non-vectorized loop works 40% faster than what is written here.

Comment: if you ask for a vectorization here, you are asking for a vectorized version of pointer dereferencing.

Comment: Sorry, this statement does not mean anything to me.

Comment: Arm/Neon only supports vector loading from contiguous data. `array[a1[i]]` is not contiguous. In order to vectorize `array[a1[i]]`, you need gather-load instructions. Which apparently Neon does not have. So no, it will not vectorize.